# Why when I load a CSV in R is the Hour data showing up as NA?

Tags: r, time, na

I am currently working on analysis of a dataset from excel that includes hour data. However, when I load the dataset into R the column which is the hour data shows up as only NAs. It also says the column is a lgl object. I tried reformatting the hour data in excel to remove the 1:00 structure to just 1, because I thought maybe that was the problem, but the same thing is happening. The data set is way too big to manually create another.

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: Welcome to SO, EJM1998! This is not something we can reproduce without seeing more of the dataset. Further, we don't know what code (or package) you are using to read the file, so even more we don't know. Please try hard to make this question self-contained and reproducible; there are good recommendations in each of these links, please take a look then come back, [edit] your question, and add some [code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and sample data. Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.